# Embedded Python(C++) Import Locks up?

Tags: python, .net, gil, python.net, winpdb

So we are using a python interpreter embedded in our C++ application (using Py_initialize,etc) to run various test scripts.

I am attempting to use the Pythonnet package.

Running a normal python interpreter i can run import clr and have no issues and can use pythonnet as expected.

If i attempt to run import clr in a script that runs in our embedded interpreter it locks up on that line.  It never throws any errors or does anything, just sits there forever and i have no idea how to figure out what its doing.

I've attempted to use WinPdb but it also just locks up when i try to enter that statement.

Comment: How are you managing the GIL? How are you using pythonnet from C++??? Can you include code samples?